# Do we have to code TypeScript in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

TypeScript is a powerset of JavaScript.

My question is whether we could only code JavaScript (without using TypeScript) in Angular 5?

Comment: You may be able to, but the question is why you would want to considering you can natively write Javascript in an Typescript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to use TypeScript.

Here is an article here that shows the basics of using Angular with ES: http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/how-to-do-everything-in-angular2-using-es6/

I was on the Angular 2 doc team and the first cut of the docs at Angular.io had placeholders for an ES only version of our content. However, as time went on we found that the vast majority of developers were using TypeScript. So all of the docs ended up with TypeScript examples.

The *vast* majority of stackoverflow examples will also be in TypeScript.

So going with straight ES is possible, but may put you on a long and lonely road.

Answer (score 1):

Much like you said, TS is a superset of js. The issue is a lot of the Angular tooling and framework is in TS, and so you could write ts files with no type annotations which will be "js" code.

However I would not recommend it as you lose the power of static type checking.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular we do have components which are coupled with html for many advantages in the form of a class. This is one of the key feature of this framework. There are other features like dependency injection which is implemented through the constructor and there is no constructor in javascript. Generally, in javascript we do not write classes the way we do it in typescript, hence most of the code can't be written with javascript.

e.g. we cannot change the syntax of a method in class from

```
private method1() {}
```

to

```
function method1() {}
```

However, you can write the javascript code inside a method of a typescript class which works perfectly fine with angular.